# Need a Windows tool that can compress a file to create a .Z file

Tags: windows, file-compression

Unix has a `compress` program based on the LZW compression algorithm that creates a file with a ".Z" extension.  I would like to be able to do that on Windows.  I was surprised to see that 7-zip does not, although it can uncompress .Z files.  Similarly, Cygwin also has an `uncompress`, but no `compress`.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Strange on Cygwin I do see uncompress and compress and there is a symbolic link between the 2. Just try `which compress` and `which uncompress`

Comment: @albert (head-smack)  D'oh.  I hadn't uploaded the optional cygwin ncompress package, and some older documentation (e.g. http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/compress-ncompress-package-for-Cygwin-td102270.html) I saw on the web said compress was unavailable.  Thanks!